# casting varchar date to int date

Tags: int, varchar

I get this message when I am joining two tables on sales dates as well.

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '12FEB2013' to data type int

my original table has dates in `12FEB2013`  format whereas the other has in `200130312`.

How can I convert it to fit 20130312?

Thing is I will be working with 4 millions rows.

I tried this:

> convert(datetime,'variable name', as 112)  --- it didnt work.

Can you guys help me?

Comment: You might want to mention what DBMS you are using …

Comment: I am on SQL Server 2012

Comment: You need a custom function made specifically for this.

Comment: Anyone,please? help would be great.